# programming g-adic expansion in c++

Tags: c++

I want to program the g-adic expansion in the c++ language, but whatever I try, the output is still wrong. Let me first explain what the g-adic expansion is. The g-adic expansion is a way to represent numbers. For example, binary numbers, this is the 2-adic expansion of numbers. And hexadecimal is 16-adic expansion. So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int g;
    cin>>x;
    cin>>g;
    int k=log(x)/log(g)+1;
    int e;
    int b=0;
    int* myArray=NULL;
    myArray=new int[k];

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        myArray[i]=0;
    }

    while(b!=k)
    {
        e=x/(g^(k-b-1));
        myArray[b]=e;
        x=x-e*g^(k-b-1);
        b++;
    }

    b=0;

    while(b!=k)
    {
        cout<<myArray[b]<<endl;
        b++;
    }

    delete [] myArray;
    myArray=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

So for example if I want to convert 105 to binary, x=105 and g=2, k is the length of the new number. In this case that is 7. int e=105/2^(7-1)=1. This is the first number. Then x=105-1*2^(7-1)=41. If you do this by hand, you will find that 105 becomes 1101001. But if I compile this piece of code, it just doesn't work. My question is what is wrong with this code?

Comment: how about formating the code first?

Comment: which subtraction is done first in here?:g^(k-b-1)

Comment: @Torsten Robitzki: i don't know what formatting is.

Comment: @user1535119 Lol, I believe you.

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: what do you mean?

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR. I bet that is very much not what you meant to do.

Comment: This is the g-ary expansion, not the g-adic. g-adic (usually p-adic, because p is usually taken to be prime) means [something different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_expansions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` doesn't do exponentiation. It's the exclusive-or operator. To do exponentiation, use the [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function.

```
e=x/std::pow(double(g),double(k-b-1));
myArray[b]=e;
x=x-e*std::pow(double(g),double(k-b-1));
```

[You can see your program in action, with my changes, on IDE One.](http://ideone.com/48BLv)

Comment: oke, now the program works, very stupid of me to think that ^ is the exponentiation operator, but i am new to this so maybe that is why i thought that. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

here: run this program

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <cmath>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int g;
    cin>>x;
    cin>>g;

    while(x>g)
    {
        cout<<x%g<<endl;
        x/=g;
    }
            cout<<x%g<<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

works for 105 and 2 and does not need an array

Comment: yes your code works, but i want to know why my code doesn't work. if i do everything what's in my code by hand, i get the good answers, but if i run the program it doesn't work.

Comment: Two problems: (1) You are outputting digits in reverse order. (2) You do the wrong thing when `x == g`. Also, (3) you can avoid code duplication by using `x > 0` as your test.

Comment: i think there is an undefined behavior at g^(k-b-1). which subtraction first? i m going to eat something im afk now

Comment: so how can i solve this undefined behaviour? and i still don't understand what you mean by which substraction first.

Comment: Subtraction operators are evaluated from left to right, always.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Maybe I'm missing something - why does it matter which subtraction in `k-b-1` is done first? In this particular case, I don't think we're dealing with overflow/underflow possibilities, so `((k-b)-1) == ((k-1)-b)`...